# Update order details in prestashop rest api

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I need to update shipping details of an order using rest api in Prestashop. I need to update Tracking no, Tracking company name etc. from rest API.
I searched a lot for this but didn't find any API. Please guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Resource is called Order_carrier
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/resources/order_carriers/